# Сохранение строки ввода в терминале

Tags: c++, linux, консоль

В учебном консольном чат-клиенте на С++ необходимы одновременый прием и отправка сообщений. Но при получении сообщения набранная строка остаётся сверху и недоступна. Есть ли какие-либо флаги `termios` или какие-нибудь настройки для того, чтобы ввод сохранялся? Например, набранные символы сразу же помещались под принятыми сообщениями вместе с курсором.

Comment: думаю, Вам нужен ncurse

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то Вам  надо разбить экран на 2 части. В одной, например, нижняя строка (строки) идет набор, а весь вывод производится в скроллируемую верхнюю часть. Если так, то предложенный @KoVadim [ncurses](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) можно попробовать.

Comment: @KoVadim @avp  `ncurses`я знаю, там достаточно сложно, пробовал несколько вариантов, но не получилось, не хочется столько времени тратить на то, что вряд ли когда-то потребуется. Могу в принципе сделать используя Qt, но надо через терминал.

Comment: @KoVadim @avp в `man` курсор как-то устанавливается внизу терминала, может, знаете как?

Comment: Вам никто не мешает посмотреть ему в сорцы - они доступны. http://www.nongnu.org/man-db/development.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил используя управляющие символы ( ECMA-48 CSI-последовательности, DEC-последовательности) которые описаны в разделе `console_codes` opennet.ru.

```
printf( "%c[2J", 27 ); // очистка всего экрана
fflush(stdout);        // эта функция немедленной отправки символов
printf( "%c[?6h", 27); // режим DECOM, для окна прокрутки
fflush(stdout);
printf( "%c[%d;%dr", 27, 1, 40); // установка окна прокрутки с 1 по 40 ряд
fflush(stdout);                 
printf( "%c[%d;%dH", 27, y_part_msg, 1 ); // установка курсора в область
fflush(stdout);  // где будут набираться сообщения
```

После установки окна прокрутки курсор будет находиться в левом верхнем углу, поэтому потребовалось переопределение позиции.

```
if (select(s+1, &readset, &writeset, NULL, &timeout) == -1)
.....
if(FD_ISSET(s, &readset)) // сработал сокет, то есть пришло сообщение
{
nbytes = recv(s, bufrcv, sizeof(bufrcv), 0);
....
// сохраняем позицию курсора, необходимо, чтобы вновь вернутья к набору 
// сообщения, после печати принятого
printf( "%c[s", 27); 
fflush(stdout);
// устанавливаем позицию курсора на 1 строку выше чем область печати
// личных сообщений
printf( "%c[%d;%dH", 27, y_part_msg-1, 1 );
//вставляем 1 строку между областями чата и печати своих сообщений
printf( "%c[1L", 27); // первая изюминка
//установка курсора в область печати сообщений чата и вывод сообщения
printf( "%c[%d;%dH", 27, y_part_chat, 1 );
fflush(stdout);
printf("%s", bufrcv);
fflush(stdout);
```

Здесь надо сделать несколько замечаний. Сообщения вставляются всегда в одну и ту же строку относительно левого верхнего угла. Избежать наложения позволяет только сдвиг рамки окна прокрутки. Без вставки новой строки это происходит автоматически при отправки своих сообщений, так как курсор переводится на строку вниз. Но, если сообщение принято от других, то сдвига рамки за счет `Enter` нет.

```
printf( "%c[%d;%dH", 27, 24, 1 );
fflush(stdout);
printf("%c", '\n');    // вторая изюминка
printf( "%c[u", 27);   // возврат к нашему сообщению
fflush(stdout);
}
```

без последнего символа перевода строки рамка не будет смещаться вниз, то есть вставка линии будет бесполезной.
У меня значения позиций чата и области набора сообщений такие:

```
int y_part_chat = 20;
int y_part_msg = 22;
```

Стоит отметить, что данный код не учитывает изменения размера окна консоли, но для учебного эмулятора чата, думаю, хватит и этого.